# What does "unpeeled" mean?

Tags: vegetables, stews, peeling

I'm looking at a recipe for pot roast, and one of the ingredients is this:

> 3 carrots, unpeeled and cut into 2-inch pieces

Am I supposed to remove the peel on the carrots, or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unpeeled means not peeled.  Do not peel the carrots.

Comment: I think what is confusing me is the word "and," which to me implies two actions I'm suppose to take (unpeel and cut). Apparently the "and" is joining two adjectives, unpeeled and cut. Thanks for clarifying. I may ignore the directions and peel them anyway. :)

Comment: @BenMiller fair point.  Perhaps the instruction would have been clearer if it read: 3 unpeeled carrots cut into 2-inch pieces.  In the end, I doubt it will make much difference in your final product.

Comment: It's a bit odd, since ordinarily a recipe like this would call for you to peel the carrots, or if not, to wash them very carefully. There's little need for it to be explicitly with the peel, not in a pot roast. I'd be tempted to interpret this as a poorly-tested recipe and move on to a recipe that was clearer...

Comment: Please unpeel some carrots for me

Comment: That would still leave you with unpeeled carrots :) ... And yes, "do not peel the mother f carrots motherf.... ", that's what it says :)